# Can updating Dell Firmware 'unlock' BIOS booting?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi

[image]

The firmware shows that the **Legacy boot mode is not selectable (greyed-out)** for some reason: I suspect that it was somehow configured this way by the previous owner.  I have identical machines: **it is possible to choose between the legacy & UEFI**: one of the two must be selected.  The goal is to enable said Dell Optiplex 7010 to boot via BIOS.  I have traversed the Dell firmware boot menus and have not seen an option to enable BIOS.  If I simply missed this any guidance (steps) to navigate is appreciated.

[image]

## QUESTIONS

- `If I could install the BIOS should I expect the settings to enable BIOS booting?`

At this point, I have only been able to install Ubuntu to the PC:

- `When updating the` [Dell Boot Firmware](https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER05066036M/1/O7010A29.exe) `(.exe), is possible to run this file only after booting up from Windows? (i.e. not Ubuntu)`

If this posting belongs in another forum please migrate to the appropriate venue

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion about UEFI versus BIOS, because a lot of people are very sloppy with terminology, even computer manufacturers themselves.

UEFI is NOT a BIOS even though many people call it that. You can't disable UEFI and fall-back to BIOS.

A computer has either a UEFI firmware or it has an old-style BIOS firmware (no EUFI at all). It is one or the other.

It is, in general, not possible to replace the UEFI firmware with a BIOS firmware. In theory it is possible, but to my knowledge no PC manufacturer has ever made a PC for which they provided both types of firmware.

If you have an installation media for an OS (like DOS/FreeDos) that expects BIOS you can still boot it from an UEFI firmware by enabling the "CSM" module. Some UEFI systems call it "legacy" mode.
This CSM module simulates the BIOS style boot-process, so the OS is happy.
In some UEFI firmware the CSM option ONLY becomes visible after you have disabled the "Secure Boot" option. The 2 are mutually exclusive.

Please note: Installing an OS in UEFI with CSM mode, means that the OS most likely won't boot anymore, if you disable the CSM later!

Answer (score 0):

[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029).

Legacy boot is greyed out when Secure Boot is enabled (these two are incompatible). You have to disable Secure Boot, save changes, enter UEFI setup again and Legacy boot will be available.

You should keep UEFI up to date anyway, updates often come with security patches.

Comment: Thanks for the comment regarding Secure Boot: I posted a photo of the Secure Boot settings.   If only it were that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't select legacy if no legacy bootable drive is available. Restart with a non uefi usb stick in and the option should become available.